# How to animate many elements React-Native Reanimated 2?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I'm trying to just make 20 - 50 stars "twinkle" (opacity change with random interval), but it's slowing the app to a crawl.

I'm using reanimated 2.2.0.

I tried sharing the opacity value but only 1 element had the styles applied, which I think may be because of this: "[Animated styles cannot be shared between views.](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/2.2.0/api/useAnimatedStyle#:%7E:text=Animated%20styles%20cannot%20be%20shared%20between%20views.)"

This is my entire component

```js
function TwinklingStar({ position, size }) {
    const starOpacity = useSharedValue(1);

    useEffect(() => {
        setInterval(() => {
            starOpacity.value = withSpring(starOpacity.value ? 0 : 1)
        }, getRandomInt(500, 1000))
    }, []);

    const twinkling = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
        opacity: starOpacity.value
    }));

    return (
        <Animated.Image 
            source={sparkleImage}
            resizeMode="cover" 
            style={[{
                width: size,
                height: size,
                position: 'absolute',
                top: position.y,
                left: position.x
            }, twinkling]} 
        />
    )
}
```

There are perhaps 5 of them per card, and a random amount of cards, 5-20 lets say.

I've read over the docs but don't think I'm understanding them properly cause I cant figure out why app is crawling/freezing/crashing. It's like all the animations are blocking the js thread, but [they should be running on ui thread since the opacity changes are "captured" by the useAnimatedStyle hook which is a "worklet"?](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/2.2.0/worklets#:%7E:text=The%20method%20provided%20to%20the%20hook%20will%20be%20turned%20into%20a%20worklet%20and%20executed%20on%20the%20UI%20thread%20automatically.)

Confused...

Comment: did you find any solution to your problem? I am currently working on this. But in my case, I don't have many stars to animate.

Comment: it would be helpful if you share the design that you want to implement.